# How to fix ": Unexpected Element("URI:"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg", local "hibernate-configuration")

Tags: hibernate, jaxb, flyway, java-11

I recently updated to Java 11( from 8 )  and I am having trouble running the **maven-flyway-plugin** as it fails reading **hibernate-configuration.xml.** Though it works when running without maven, so it seems to be a maven class loading issue. Any help on how to fix this  would be appreciated

This line in my source triggers the error. I am using **hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar**

**new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("c:\hibernate-cfg.xml")**;

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unexpected Element (URI:"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg", local:"hibernate-configuration"). Unexpected Elements are <{}hibernate-configuration>
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent (UnmarshallingContext.java:744)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError (Loader.java:262)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError (Loader.java:257)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement (Loader.java:124)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement (UnmarshallingContext.java:1149)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement (UnmarshallingContext.java:574)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement (UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement (ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:102)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement (InterningXmlVisitor.java:75)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.handleStartElement (StAXEventConnector.java:261)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.bridge (StAXEventConnector.java:130)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0 (UnmarshallerImpl.java:460)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal (UnmarshallerImpl.java:435)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal (JaxbCfgProcessor.java:126)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal (JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlFile (ConfigLoader.java:76)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure (StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:169
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the following post simply **preloading** the class solves the problem. Though why maven has this class loading issues remains unanswered

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12893